# When the train start to go / move / something else?

Tags: word-request

While talking about a bus or a train, what's the correct way to refer to his leaving the main train station? Is there a specific term like departure for airplane.

I thought about "When the train **goes / moves** to Cardiff" something else? But I'm not sure if it's natural.

Answer (score 2):

Pulls away is usually used for trains. To add more context, one might say:

> The train pulls away from the station.

In the context above this doesn't really fit though. The following may suffice:

> When the train travels to Cardiff.

Or

> When the train leaves for Cardiff.

It depends on the context you're using it in though

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> When the train *leaves for* Cardiff

*to leave for* means:

> 2. To set out for some destination.
>      *What time do you leave for the airport in the morning?
>
>      They're leaving for New York next week, so I'm having a going-away party for them this Saturday.*

(source: [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+for+some+place) - I've left out the sentence which is erroneously duplicated from definition 3)